# How to create a subclass of Button in Kivy, python

Tags: python, kivy

I have created a button subclass myButt using the method "@". But every time interpreter showing error. I am new to Kivy and have some basic knowledge of python. Please help.

```
<myButt@ToggleButton>:
    color: .8,.9,0,1
    font_size: 20
    background_color: 0,1,1,1
    group: 'a'

<simpleLayout>:
    padding: 10
    spacing: 10
    myButt:
        text: 'Hello'
        pos_hint: {'x': 0, 'y': 0}
        size_hint: 0.7, 0.5
    myButt:
        text: 'World!'
        pos_hint: {'top': 1, 'right': 1}
        size_hint: 0.3, 0.5
```

But it showing error:
        line 15
         text: 'World!'
             ^
     SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Reason

Dynamic class cannot start with lower case letter.

## Solution

Replace `myButt` with `MyButt`

## Output

[image: Result]